# How to make Azure Media Service hosted video auto play on mobile?

Tags: azure, mobile, video-streaming, azure-web-app-service, azure-media-services

I am working on a project where by we are hosting and streaming video through Azure Media Service.

There is a particular video we have positioned as the hero background upon entry to the site. On desktop the video auto-play's and streams just fine but on mobile it does not autoplay at all. It simply showcases the preview image.

I'd love to be able to paste a link to the site but unfortunately due to the confidentiality of the project I am not able to. However, if there is something in particular you'd like me to post to help support the question please let me know.

The web-app is build using Angular.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with the browser platform you are targeting on the mobile applications. Most mobile browsers have disabled autoplay.  User MUST now initiate all playback actions.

Since the release of iOS 10 Apple has allowed muted video autoplay: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Chrome 53 on Android also allowing muted video autoplay: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay

Comment: Thank you johndeu. 'User MUST now initiate all playback actions' - that's the ticket right there.